# Using IF and Temp Table with variables, and BEGIN/END statements

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to create a temp table based on an IF statement.  I don't think I've used IF statements much, so I'm probably missing some logic.  When I run the following code, I get an error message stating *'There is already an object named '#T1' in the database.'*

What am I missing?

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#T1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T1;

BEGIN
    DECLARE @roleName AS VARCHAR(20) = 'role1';
    DECLARE @userName AS VARCHAR(20) = 'user1';
    DECLARE @schemaName AS VARCHAR(20) = 'schema1';

    IF @roleName = ''
        --OR   @userName IS NULL
        BEGIN

            SELECT      NEWID () AS ID
                      , dp.name  AS DB_PrincipalsName
                      , us.name  AS SysUsersName
            INTO        #T1
            FROM        sys.sysusers              us
            RIGHT JOIN  sys.database_role_members rm ON us.uid = rm.member_principal_id
            JOIN        sys.database_principals   dp ON rm.role_principal_id = dp.principal_id
            ORDER BY    us.name;
        END;
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT      NEWID () AS ID
                      , dp.name  AS DB_PrincipalsName
                      , us.name  AS SysUsersName
            INTO        #T1
            FROM        sys.sysusers              us
            RIGHT JOIN  sys.database_role_members rm ON us.uid = rm.member_principal_id
            JOIN        sys.database_principals   dp ON rm.role_principal_id = dp.principal_id
            WHERE       dp.name LIKE '%' + @roleName + '%'
            ORDER BY    us.name;
        END;

    SELECT  ID
          , DB_PrincipalsName
          , SysUsersName
    FROM    #T1;
END;
```

Comment: This is a parsing error. You are trying to create the same object, `#T1`, in the same batch twice. It doesn't matter that neither can be run in the same run, there are still 2 (effective) `CREATE` statements for the same object and so the parsing fails.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is already an object named '#tmptable' in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989594/there-is-already-an-object-named-tmptable-in-the-database)

Comment: No, this question is different as I'm using an If statement and the question is in regards mainly to that issue.  I was thinking it wouldn't create it if the 'if' wasn't satisfied.  This is a different angle regarding temp table creation than the question you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying `SELECT INTO` causes the interpreter to attempt to create the table.  In this case twice.  You could try `INSERT INTO` instead.  Something like this

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#T1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T1;
go
create table #T1(
    ID                              uniqueidentifier not null,
    DB_PrincipalsName               sysname not null,
    SysUsersName                    sysname not null);

BEGIN
    DECLARE @roleName AS VARCHAR(20) = 'role1';
    DECLARE @userName AS VARCHAR(20) = 'user1';
    DECLARE @schemaName AS VARCHAR(20) = 'schema1';

    IF @roleName = ''
        --OR   @userName IS NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #T1
            SELECT      NEWID () AS ID
                      , dp.name  AS DB_PrincipalsName
                      , us.name  AS SysUsersName
            FROM        sys.sysusers              us
            RIGHT JOIN  sys.database_role_members rm ON us.uid = rm.member_principal_id
            JOIN        sys.database_principals   dp ON rm.role_principal_id = dp.principal_id
            ORDER BY    us.name;
        END;
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #T1
            SELECT      NEWID () AS ID
                      , dp.name  AS DB_PrincipalsName
                      , us.name  AS SysUsersName
            FROM        sys.sysusers              us
            RIGHT JOIN  sys.database_role_members rm ON us.uid = rm.member_principal_id
            JOIN        sys.database_principals   dp ON rm.role_principal_id = dp.principal_id
            WHERE       dp.name LIKE '%' + @roleName + '%'
            ORDER BY    us.name;
        END;

    SELECT  ID
          , DB_PrincipalsName
          , SysUsersName
    FROM    #T1;
END;
```

Comment: It's been updated with the table definition

Comment: Aside: The table can be created using `select`/`into` prior to the `if` statement. Just modify it so that no rows are inserted, e.g. by adding `where 1 = 0; -- Create empty table with correct schema.`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to explicitly create your #T1 temp table before getting entering the `IF` scope, then your `INSERT`s should work as expected.

```
CREATE TABLE #T1
 (
  ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
  DB_PrincipalsName SYSNAME NOT NULL,
  SysUsersName SYSNAME NOT NULL
 )
```

The optimizer doesn't necessarily follow instructions the same way a procedural language does, and may evaluate items in an unexpected order relative to when it creates them.

Comment: Of course it interprets them the same way: it compiles it first. In this case, `INTO` is the same as `CREATE TABLE` and you can't create the same table twice in one batch

Comment: My point was that the engine will interpret instructions consistently with itself, but not necessarily consistently with procedural languages, which aren't even consistent with one another.